# Xcode: Go to First Page in Storyboard when app longer then 5 minutes in Background?

Tags: ios, xcode, background, storyboard, execute

I'm trying my first App in Xcode... and have a question about working with storyboards:

I have: 
-Tab Bar Controller (first) connected with two navigation Controllers ... after each Navigation Controller is a View Controller...

Question:
is it possible (maybe with applicationWillEnterForeground) that my app switches to one of these View Controllers if my app is longer then 5 minutes in background? ... or that it starts with my "first" view in my app again? Because i want to reload my location-finder if the user moved with his phone.

tried some code i found on the web in my "applicationDidEnterBackground" (in AppDelegate.m), but can't bring it to work :(

(or should/could i make a seque from each view to a "first view" and call it in my "applicationWillEnterForeground"?)

Hope i could explain it that u understand my question ;)

best regards
gerhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you need to do is change the selected view controller of your tabBarController you can achieve it putting this code in your `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to go back to the first controller in your navigation stack you can do it like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: ok, that is working :) ... but: is it possible to call the "first view" of one of the navigation controllers? with your great solution i come to my "first" tab, but "in this tab" i have a navigation controller with some views... if i'm the third view and i bring the app to background, there again appears the third view after EnterForeground. Hope u understand my bad english :-/ ... it should come to the screen that appears when i start my app up from ground. (or would it be easier to execute the app in background?)

Comment: yes, I understand your question, I will try something and then edit my answer, give a minute ;)

Comment: try the code in the EDIT section, I try it in a demo project and it works for me, hope this solve your problem

Comment: ok! big thanks! Is the same way possible if i have a navigation-controller with a lot of views behind? (really my last question today :-) )

Comment: the number of views in the stack shouldn't be a problem